# Angular 8 Material specific mat-option not selected on update

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

In angular 8 mat-option not selected specific option. **I have put static option then working fine. But, its not working on dynamic mat-option.**

```
<mat-label>Item Category  {{item.category_id}}</mat-label>
<mat-select name="category_id" [(ngModel)]="item.category_id" #category_id="ngModel" required>
<mat-option *ngFor="let cat of categoriesData" [value]="cat.id" >
    {{cat.category_title}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: prepare stackblitz

Comment: maybe caltegoriesData items has no `id`

Comment: id is available in caltegoriesData

Comment: How can I know that? Make that stackblitz.

Comment: Try use compareWith: (o1: any, o2: any) => boolean

Answer (score 0):

I have to resolve this issue. this is amazing issue.

**My option value variable is Int (Like: 1) and found ngmodel value is string from server api (Like: "1")**

```
<mat-label>Item Category  {{item.category_id}}</mat-label>
<mat-select name="category_id" [(ngModel)]="item.category_id" #category_id="ngModel" required> // found ngmodel variable value is string from server api (like "1")
<mat-option *ngFor="let cat of categoriesData" [value]="cat.id" > // cat.id variable is int (like: 1)
    {{cat.category_title}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```